# Easy Digital Downloads – Frontend Submission Plugin Customisation ACF Fields and Hooks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, easy-digital-downloads

Is there a way to integrate ACF fields into an Easy Digital Downloads Front End Submissions plugin? I need to add fields to the add/edit new product submission forms.

I’m looking to add custom fields not already present in the submission form editor on Easy Digital Downloads’ Front End Submission plugin add-on.

One of the ‘blocks’ in the user-submission form editor allows me to add an ‘Action Hook’ which seemingly allows me to hook any function I want into the form. The help for that block is as follows:

> This is for developers to add dynamic elements as they want. It
>   provides the chance to add whatever input type you want to add in this
>   form.
>
> You can bind your own functions to render the form to this action
>   hook. You’ll be given 3 parameters to play with: `$form_id`, `$post_id`,
>   `$form_settings`.
>
> ```
> add_action(‘{hookname}’, ‘my_function_name}’, 10, 3 );
> // first param: Form Object
> // second param: Save ID of post/user/custom
> // third param: Field Object
> function my_function_name( $form, $save_id, $field ) {
>     // Do whatever you want here
> }
> ```

Using that, would it possible for me to add ACF fields/elements, or indeed an entire fieldset, into the EDD frontend submission form?

If so, how would I go about doing this?